# How does my university's network keep track of my computer?

Tags: networking, recording

I live in a university and uses the university’s wireless network. In order for students to access the internet, they must first “activate” (register) their devices (e.g., laptops, tablets) on the school’s network. When they first open a web browser, they are taken to the activation page where they must sign in using their student ID.

This only needs to be done once. Once the device is activated/registered, the network seems to remember the device and does not require additional activation.

My question is: Which information about my computer did the school’s network obtain (which they can use to identify the computer as mine)? I am not very knowledgeable about IT. I am sure there is some information that is unique to my computer that the network can then use to distinguish it from other computers (and to match the computer with my name since I registered it with my school ID.) What is this information that the network keeps in record?

Also, is there a way for me to change my computer’s information so that the network will no longer recognize the computer as mine? I would have to activate it again to use the internet, but I would still like to know if this is possible.

Comment: There are many different ways to do that. Probably they use only activation through the web browser an you choosed to remeber the password (stay logged on) and / or they use cookies. To check this you can delete your browser history (including cookeys and logons). Then you will presumably be asked to logon again. (But take care, you will also loose the logons to other websites you are using now withoug logging in.)

Comment: Have you asked one of the systems administrators at your university about this?  As they maintain and support the system their answer would be definitive in your case.  Otherwise feedback from us is conjecture based on how we all might configure such a network.

Answer (score 0):

It will be tracked using your machine mac address along with your machine ip

You can find your Machine mac address using following steps

**open Network and sharing center**

[image]

**open Local Area connection and click details to view your device mac address.**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The IP address is assigned by the network. As such, it is not suitable for uniquely identifying devices.

Comment: Also, it is fairly difficult to obtain your MAC address unless their system interrogates its own arp tables; but then the server and LAN subnets should be on the same segment. The most common seems to be a cookie of some sort. At my work place, though, the captive portal uses the MAC address as the tables are cleared every 9hrs or so. We've tested re-imaging and it still worked without having to log in.

Comment: @BigChris It’s not really difficult. Access points could simply ask a RADIUS server about which VLAN a client should be assigned to (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that it is most likely that they only save your mac address, witch is not very safe as you are able to use a fake mac if you know what you are doing.

The problem is that it is easy to get another users mac address when they are connected to the network over wireless, and when you have the mac address you can easily change your mac address to the same and be logged in as another student.

[WikiHow.com page "How to Change a Computer's Mac Address in Windows"](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-a-Computer%27s-Mac-Address-in-Windows)

2. They could also have planted a cookie on your computer when you logged in (the same way as you can make facebook login automatic), you can test that by cleaning your pc with eg ccleaner.

But it is hard to say for sure without some testing on the network.

Comment: I've worked as a network tech in a similar deployment, we validated via MAC but used NT credentials  with a RADIUS server on top of that to stop spoofing. It would be strange just to register MAC, but college admins are known for doing really strange things.